# How to get overflow hidden like effect in svg tiny

Tags: svg, scroll, css

I am bound to use SVG Tiny as it is the only version supported by the browser. How can I achieve an effect similar to `overflow: hidden` in this version (I have to implement a scrolling effect).

Comment: What browser? Does the implementation support 'clip-path' (even though it's not in tiny)?

Comment: It was in fact some version of Ekioh browser, forgot which one. It had some sort of clipping, rectangle or something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Structure your content so that you draw the scrolling stuff first, then draw other things on top so that it looks clipped. Note that this can be expensive if the things on top are complex to draw, so for the things that cover the parts you don't want to see I'd recommend one or more solid color rects.